# Advanced Search Type, extra whitespace on the tooltip

Tags: bug, design, search

As you can see in the screenshot below, there is some extra whitespace on the second line of the `title` attribute:

[image]

Here is the code taken from the site:

```html
<table>
<tr title="Search for community wiki posts (yes)
    Search for non-community wiki posts (no)">
                <td></td>
                <td>wiki:no</td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

I know it's not a big/critical issue but I think it can be easily fixed:

```html
<table>
<tr title="Search for community wiki posts (yes)
Search for non-community wiki posts (no)">
                <td></td>
                <td>wiki:no</td>
            </tr>
</table>
```